# Make Disable-Enable Option with jQuery

Tags: html

i need some help to make a button for enable or disable 2 div with jquery. i have 2 kind of navigation code in my page. these are my codes:

First:

```
<div class="nextprev">
[prev-link]Previous[/prev-link]
[next-link]Next[/next-link]
</div>
```

Second:

```
<div id="page_navigation1" class="page_navigation1">[next-link]Next[/next-link]</div>
```

Now, i need some jquery code for enable or disable these div's. for example, when we click on enable button just first div will be working and when we click on disable, just second div will be working!

i hope u guys undrstand my question and im sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

the toggle() function toggles the visibility of a div. so maybe something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/UvWEu/17/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDivs() {
        $("#nav1").toggle();
        $("#nav2").toggle();
    }
</script>


<div id="nav1" 
     style="background-color:red;width:50px;height:50px;display:none;">nav1
</div>
<div id="nav2" 
     style="background-color:green;width:50px; height:50px;display:visible;">nav2
</div>
<button text="toggle" style="width:50px; height=18px" onclick="toggleDivs();" />​
```

Comment: thanks, but hide and show is not working for me. i need to disable codes in one of these div's. i want to enable and disable ajax page loading with these div